# Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I am calling a GetSerialNo function but it showing some error like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
int slNo= GetSerailNo(keydata);

private int GetSerailNo(String keydata)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=Servername;database=DBNAME;uid=Username;pwd=Pwd;max pool size=250;Connect Timeout=0");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select isnull(max(slno)+1,1) from d001docs where source_keydata='" + keydata + "'", con);
    dynamic no = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    return no;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just copy and paste the error message? People, just use copy+paste!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

returns a decimal, which you need to convert to int before you return it, for example:

```
return Convert.ToInt32(no);
```

Comment: IMO From a long time `ExecuteScalar` return `object`

Comment: The return type of the method is object. However, the actual type of the result at runtime is, in this case, a decimal.

Comment: Indeed he has used dynamic in that place

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
int no = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```