# Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I'm coding in C#, and I need to do some multiplication with `Decimal` or `Double` values, however, I keep getting the error in the title.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            int caloriesBurned;

            if (radioButtonMale.Checked == true)
            {
                Decimal textBoxInt = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
                Decimal maleusage = 0.44M;

                caloriesBurned = Decimal.Multiply(maleusage, textBoxInt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Indtast venligst et tal");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Solved it! Thanks guys! Newbie mistake. Sorry!

Comment: Change `int caloriesBurned;` to `decimal caloriesBurned;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662050/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-decimal-to-int-an-explicit-conversion-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to declare the variable as decimal, like this:

```
decimal caloriesBurned;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign `decimal` to an `int` Type

```
caloriesBurned = Decimal.Multiply(maleusage, textBoxInt);
```

Change your field type to decimal as the calculation above returns a Decimal ...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply 2 decimal variables and then trying to set the value to a integer value, in order to do that you could do this:

```
caloriesBurned = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Multiply(maleusage, textBoxInt));
```

But by doing so you would lose all digits after the `,` so it you would benefit from making the `caloriesBurned` a `decimal` type instead of a `int` that way the code will work.