# Increase number of Copies of TextBox data when Printing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am able  to print the contents of a `TextBox`. What i am now trying to do is increase the number of copies that are printed. Im trying to do this using this   `document.PrinterSettings.Copies = numQuantity.Value;`.

```
numQuantity
```

is  a `NumbericUpDown Control`

But i get this error;

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'short'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

My Code:

```
private void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(txtName.Text, new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog.Document = document;

    document.PrinterSettings.Copies = numQuantity.Value;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        document.Print();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like it's pretty clear... convert your `decimal` (from the `NumericUpDown`) to a `short`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276697/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-decimal-to-int-an-explicit-conversion-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
document.PrinterSettings.Copies = Convert.ToInt16(numQuantity.Value);
```